TemplateDoesNotExist at / (Django)
Trying to my create a home page, with django.  I keep running into a TemplateDoesNotExist at error.
Im pretty sure it has something to do with my paths set up. I havent worked with django enough to debug this :(



Im trying to display an index.html file
My directory with all the files in them

Your index.html is in the wrong directory. To fix this error, create a folder named templates in your app directory (i.e. learning_logs). In the templates folder, create another folder named learning_logs and put your index.html file there. So your path should look like this:
learning_logs\templates\learning_logs\index.html
This is assuming you left the default TEMPLATES setting in your settings.py. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#templates

I tried but gave me a different error

Please share the error it gave you.

lied it worked, forgot to save before rerunning<3

one more thing Mr.16171413, do i put all new pages in this folder I created?

All templates for app learning_logs should be in that folder.  If you create another app, say users, and you want to have templates such as sign up.html, login.html etc, you need to follow the same process to create your templates
